# How to force an image to shrink to fit in flexbox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for almost two weeks now and I am still completely lost. I'm making a simple landing page and I don't want any scrolling. I need a header followed by a bootstrap row containing a paragraph and an image. Here is my ms paint example:

[image]

Simple enough right? Well I can not for the life of me figure out how to get that image to shrink to fit into that row. Here is what is happening to me now. Note: When you run the snippet on stackoverflow the window is to small. It is easier to see whats going on with the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davdarobis/5hzkbowv/11/)

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  background-color: white;
}

.banner {
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
          
<div class="banner">

  <h1>
    Header
  </h1>

  <div class="row content">
    <p> Hello World </p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

The part that throws me off is that the `.row` extends beyond it's parent container `.banner`. How do we force this to stay inside that red area?

I've messed with object-fit, flex-grow, flex-shrink, a flex-basis and none of these seem to create the desired behavior. I'm going insane trying to figure this problem out. Maybe flexbox is the wrong tool to use here? But I'm trying to take advantage of the bootstrap grid system's media queries. Thanks in advance for any help!

Note: The reason I have everything nested in the `<div class=".banner">` is because I want the header to have a shadow onto the red background.

**Edit**
The root of my question is how do I get an image to fit inside of a row that only covers the red area?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can update your code like below:

```css
img {
  /* this will make the image stretch and no overflow*/
  height:0;
  min-height:100%;
  /**/
}

h1 {
  background-color: white;
}

.banner {
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
          
<div class="banner d-flex flex-column"> <!-- flex container here -->
  <h1>
    Header
  </h1>
  <div class="d-flex content flex-grow-1 p-2"> <!-- flex-grow here to fill remaining space -->
    <p> Hello World </p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png" class="ml-auto">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works! Although I'm a little confused why this works and mine didnt?

Comment: @DallinDavis I considered an extra flexbox container as you can see and the trick height:0;min-height:100% that will avoid the overflow issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
    <div class="banner">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-6">
          <p> Hello World</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Working example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/demartini/pen/ZEQeRpZ).

PS.: In my example I tried to follow your `ms paint example`.

Comment: Wow! You are a wizard! Would you mind explaining to me what was wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem is that you have not placed any `col-*` within the `row`. Take a look at the Bootstrap [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) documentation.

Comment: With your solution I can not set the height of `.banner` . I would like to set `.banner{height:80%}`. But if I do this to your solution, the original problem is back.

Comment: Can you explain to me why you need 80% height?

Comment: Design purposes. I think the white stripe at the bottom looks nice. Or I've even considered adding a form in that bottom 20%.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `display:block` to the `img` & this also helps in responsiveness you can check the fiddle if you want to explore.

OR

> You can also look into `vh` for height and `vw` for width that will take care of all screen resolutions.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/zwd8bpqv/5/) to playaround.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div class="row content">
  <p> Hello World </p>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I just updated my code to more accurately reflect my actual project. Unfortunately setting `display: block` doesn't work with the updated code. Still thanks though!

Comment: I just made a working snippet in the above fiddle, you just have to play around with your desired `height` for `content` class and use the code for `img` as I shared.

Comment: There is a slight difference in our code. My updated code has everything nested in a `.banner` div.  `.banner` sets `height:90%`. Then, `.row`'s height is configured by flexbox. I do this because I want the header to cast a shadow onto `.banner`.  Sorry I don't know if that makes any sense?

Comment: I got it since both `banner` and `content` has same background that's why you were not able to differentiate the colors, this https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/zwd8bpqv/14/ will show you the colors and to fit to the banner you have to make `100%` for `content` class since `banner` is the parent, I guess you got it this time.

Comment: So the main problem I'm having here is that if I set `.content { height: 100%}` the image extends beyond the red.  That is because the red area is not as big as the parent '.banner`. Sorry I might be making this unnecessarily complex. My biggest problem is I really don't know what the height of that red area is?